# PHP extract substring from strings in text

Tags: php, regex, text, substring, text-extraction

I'have a text composed of many strings and for each string, if the check is true, I would like to get a specific one having some attributes:

1. the string starts with a sign like "atm"
2. after the sign there is a numeric part with a variable lenght

i.e. the word could be like atm123456 or atm7890

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Show us some of your code, what you have tried, etc.

Comment: i have not done anything yet, i can't figure out the solution..

Comment: something like substr($text, $start-point, $lenght) but how to calculate the lenght of the numeric part only?

Comment: @Luke `substr` is also a good way to do yes, to calculate the length of the numeric part you could just read from 4 to the end of the string.

Comment: @ClémentMalet thank you, the problem is that the numeric part has a variable lenght and after the numeric part there is a space and then another string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression and `preg_match()` function

```
$string = "atm123456";
$pattern = "(atm\d+)";
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches); // you may use preg_match_all() as well
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => atm123456
)
```

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/Tb2y8r) | [Regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/lB5tI3/1)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
    $thestring='atm123456';
    $thestrToEx = explode(' ',$thestring );
    $thestrToExArr=array_walk($thestrToEx,'intval');
    $theValues=explode($thestrToExArr,$thestring);
    echo $thestrToExArr.$theValues[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

in case of multiple value or repeated items. you can use `preg_match_all` like this

```
$string = "atm123456 with atm7890 items";
$pattern = "(atm\d+)";
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: sir, I just give the option in case of preg_match_all with string example, you were just considering preg_match only.

Comment: it's like the solution by hex494D49 btw it's ok

Comment: It was already mentioned in my answer; even in my regex demo. I'm ok with that, just... weird to me man. Well, have fun ;)